# How to align elements using a ChartBar from Chart.js and Alerts from Bootstrap 4?

Tags: c#, html, bootstrap-4, chart.js

Good morning, I have a topic for arranging a bar chart using Chart.js with bootstrap 4 alerts. Let me explain, in the following image I show how my elements are somewhat misaligned:

[image]

what I'm trying to do is accommodate the alerts that are found at the bottom, to the right of my bar graph.

but for some reason I can't find the way to position them correctly, I show you my html code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/BoxInfo.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <strong>Panel de Control</strong>  <small>Version 1.0</small>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <canvas id="ChartCitas"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="alert-wrap">
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <i class="fas fa-medkit fa-2x"></i> <strong>CITAS TOTALES:</strong> 964.00
                        </div>

                        <div class="alert alert-info">
                            <i class="fas fa-users fa-2x"></i> <strong>PACIENTES TOTALES:</strong> 3.00
                        </div>

                        <div class="alert alert-warning">
                            <i class="fas fa-user-md fa-2x"></i> <strong>MÉDICOS TOTALES:</strong> 25.00
                        </div>

                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <i class="fas fa-hospital-alt fa-2x"></i> <strong>CONSULTORIOS TOTALES:</strong> 47.00
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ChartCitas").getContext("2d");
    var MyChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Numero de citas',
                data: [20, 36, 51, 10, 9, 78, 64, 18, 78, 85, 11, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgb(0, 153, 255, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(163, 0, 204, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(0, 51, 17, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(255, 102, 0, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(179, 179, 0, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(0, 255, 255, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(204, 51, 0, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(68, 204, 0, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(0, 0, 204, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(102, 0, 102, 0.5)',
                    'rgb(102, 153, 255, 0.5)'
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

In my HTML code, I try to dock the graph as the alerts inside a div class = "row" and in a card both elements. I also tried a FORM-INLINE but still without success

and this is my css code to add style to my alerts:

```css
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

    .alert:hover, .alert:focus {
        transform: scale(1.04);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 20px #e8e8e8;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 20px #e8e8e8;
    }

.alert-wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    /*margin-right: 400px;*/
    /*margin-left:1150px;*/
}

.alert .close {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.alert:hover .close, .alert:focus .close {
    opacity: .2;
}

.alert i {
    min-width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.alert-success {
    background: rgb(214,233,198);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(214,233,198,1) 0%, rgba(198,233,229,1) 100%);
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}

.alert-info {
    background: rgb(188,232,241);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(188,232,241,1) 0%, rgba(188,208,241,1) 100%);
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}

.alert-warning {
    background: rgb(250,235,204);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(250,235,204,1) 0%, rgba(250,227,204,1) 100%);
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}

.alert-danger {
    background: rgb(235,204,209);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(235,204,209,1) 0%, rgba(235,204,221,0.927608543417367) 100%);
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

So it's basically what I try to do, but without having the accommodation I want to get to.

If you need more information and / or any questions I will be aware, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/), you have to define a `.row` around both your `.col-md-8` and `.col` containers. Next, remove the `width: 30%` styles and everything will work properly, as you will see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsr7b4Lk/3/):

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <canvas id="ChartCitas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="alert-wrap">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <i class="fas fa-medkit fa-2x"></i> <strong>CITAS TOTALES:</strong> 964.00
                </div>

                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-users fa-2x"></i> <strong>PACIENTES TOTALES:</strong> 3.00
                </div>

                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-md fa-2x"></i> <strong>MÉDICOS TOTALES:</strong> 25.00
                </div>

                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <i class="fas fa-hospital-alt fa-2x"></i> <strong>CONSULTORIOS TOTALES:</strong> 47.00
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Image of the result]

If you additionally want to optimized the mobile view, replace your `.alert-wrap` by a `.row` and set a `<div class="col-6 col-md-12">` around your `.alert`'s as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsr7b4Lk/14/):

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3">
            <canvas id="ChartCitas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col mt-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <i class="fas fa-medkit fa-2x"></i> <strong>CITAS TOTALES:</strong> 964.00
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-users fa-2x"></i> <strong>PACIENTES TOTALES:</strong> 3.00
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-md fa-2x"></i> <strong>MÉDICOS TOTALES:</strong> 25.00
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <i class="fas fa-hospital-alt fa-2x"></i> <strong>CONSULTORIOS TOTALES:</strong> 47.00
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Resulting in this mobile view and nearly the same desktop view as above:

[image: Mobile view result]

Comment: wow!! amazing answer!! 
it worked perfectly!!! THANKS!! 
in fact, i thought to will make a mobile view after the desktop view, with your answer, i have an idea how to make it.
best regards!!

Comment: Thanks.! I will try to improve it a little more
regards partner!